# Nodejs child_process execute shell command

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, shell, child-process

I am working on a university project where I have to evaluate the security threats to an open WiFi Network.I have chosen the aircrack-ng set of tools for penetration testing. My project uses Node js for the rich set of features. However, I am a beginner and am struggling to solve a problem. Firstly, I shall present my code and then pose the problem.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var nic = "wlan2";

//obtain uid number of a user for spawing a new console command
//var uidNumber = require("uid-number");
// uidNumber("su", function (er, uid, gid) {
//  console.log(uid); 
// });

//Check for monitor tools
var airmon_ng= spawn('airmon-ng');
airmon_ng.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  nicList = data.toString().split("\n");
  //use for data binding
  console.log(nicList[0]);//.split("\t")[0]);
});

//airmon start at the nic(var)
var airmon_ng_start = spawn('airmon-ng',['start',nic]).on('error',function(err){console.log(err);});
airmon_ng_start.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log(data.toString());
});

var airmon_ng_start = spawn('airodump-ng',['mon0']).on('error',function(err){console.log(err);});
airmon_ng_start.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
console.log(data.toString());
});
```

As seen in the above code. I use the child_process.spwan to execute the shell command. In the line "var airmon_ng_start = spawn(......" the actual command executes in the terminal and doesn`t end till the ctrl+c is hit and it regularly updates the list of Wi-Fi networks available in the vicinity . My goal is to identify the network that I wish to test for vulnerability. However when I execute the command the process goes to an infinite loop and waits for the shell command to terminate (which never terminates until killed) moreover I wish to use the stdout stream to display the new set of data as the Wi-Fi finds and updates. May the node.js experts provide me with  a better way to do this ?

2) Also I with to execute some commands as root . how may this be done . For now I am running the javascript as a root. However, in the project I wish to execute only some of the commands as root and not the entire js file as root. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

```
//inherit parent`s stdout stream
var airmon_ng_start = spawn('airodump-ng',['mon0'],{ stdio: 'inherit' })
.on('error',function(err){console.log(err);});
```

Found this solution. Simply inherit parent`s stdout